# Showcase, share or brag about an answer

Tags: discussion, answers, privileges

Sometimes a great question is asked, you answer it, get the answer accepted with 1 upvote and the answer is forgotten.

There are two cases that bother me here:

1. I've posted my answer but I'm not 100% sure it is correct and want others to check it
2. My answer is sooooo awesome, I want everybody to see it.

I think it would be nice to have a privilege to nominate your answer to be displayed in some parallel feed with a request for others to look at it and voice their opinion.

Comment: Tweet about it.  Then your followers can check it out if they like.

Comment: @jinguy I blocked all the people who follow me. I thought they were stalking me...

Comment: All 5 of them?  Cool!

Comment: 5? That's way more than I have.

Comment: "I think it would be nice to have a privilege to nominate your answer to be displayed in some parallel feed with a request for others to look at it and voice their opinion." Except this would be totally useless once everyone else finds out about it.

Comment: If there were some where to showcase or brag about an answer I am sure it would ultimately end up just linking directly to Jon Skeets profile.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly the answer you are looking for, but one way, is to make a worthwhile edit to your answer. That will put it on the 'active' list and get it at least a handful of new views in a short space of time. I first spotted this a couple of months ago when I edited a seemingly ancient answer of mine. When I hit refresh ten or so minutes later, I was shocked (and uber pleased) to find that it had received four new upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not so important whether a question is great or not. (BTW what is a great question ? I think that may be rather subjective).

Important is that when someone asks a question, the same or a similar question are found easily and their answers can be used.

Having a problem already **solved** is preferable to a problem which is solved **quickly**.